# Flask restart / shutdown callback

Tags: python, flask

I’m using Flask on a Raspberry Pi for an IoT application.

My problem is, that I need to cleanly close the connection to my external device before the application is shutdown or restarted by the Flask auto-reloader.

Is there any callback / handler / event / etc. I can use for a clean shutdown? (that also works with the auto-reloader)

Comment: do you already know the `teardown_appcontext` method on `app` ? i'm not sure there is an equivalent for the restart. Plan B could be to turn off the debug mode to avoid the auto-reload on file changes

Comment: I already tried the teardown_appcontext approach, unfortunately it is called every time when a HTTP connection is closed, not when the actual app is closed. The name appcontext is a bit misleading.
I also tried atexit, but this is only triggered at exit, not at a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application shutdown is not part of the WSGI server standard. There is no general way to know when the server stops completely from within the application code.